# Cannot open PMML file in order to make predictions from user inputs in PyPMML

Tags: python, spss, pmml

I am trying to use PyPMML https://github.com/autodeployai/pypmml to evaluate inputs obtained via a GUI. The inputs will be scored with a PMML model (constructed in SPSS) and then present the predicted class to the user. Think of it like one of those basic online BMI calculators, except instead of a simple calculation, the inputs are fed into a PMML decision tree model.

The following code:

```
from pypmml import Model
model = Model.load(r'C:\Users\localpharma\Desktop\Example.xml')
```

Gives the error message

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

This is definitely the correct file path:
[Screenshot of file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhvDo.png)

Also the following prints True

```
example = open(r'C:\Users\localpharma\Desktop\Example.xml', 'r')
print(example.readable())
```

I'm definitely making a really simple error, also if anyone knows of any easier way to score inputs with pmml in python (or any other means, just not in SPSS for **so many** different reasons) let me know!

Answer (score 0):

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

The business logic of PyPMML is written in Scala/Java, and requires a Java installation to run.

The above `FileNotFoundError` is about a missing `java.exe` (Java interpreter). It is not about your PMML file.

You need to install Java to solve the problem. Or if the Java is already installed, you must add `java.exe` to system path.